# VBA Excel - Evaluate function - How to add before multipling

Tags: vba, excel

I have this piece of code right now:

```
    LR = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("P2:P" & LR) = Evaluate("I2:I" & LR & "*O2:O" & LR)
```

As you can see, this code is multipling each entry from the I column with the corresponding entry in the O column and putting that value into column P.

Now I need to modify this code so it adds the respective values from colum I with the ones from column J and **then** multiplies that with the entry from column O. If I just write this

```
  Range("P2:P" & LR) = Evaluate("I2:I" & LR & "J2:J" & LR & "*O2:O" & LR)
```

it will obviously not work because it will mathematically multiply J with O before making a summ of I and J. How can I tell it to summ I and J together first?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use brackets! `5 + 3 * 2    =    5 + 6    =    11` and `(5 + 3) * 2     =    8 * 2    =    16` you should have had this at school math this is basic calculation ([Order of Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Arithmetic/Order_of_Operations)).

Comment: I did, but I added the brackets before the semicolon and it didn't work. Thank you either way, @Peh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Peh wrote in his comment, just add `()` for the add to work before the multiply:

```
Range("P2:P" & LR).Value = Evaluate("(I2:I" & LR & "+J2:J" & LR & ")*O2:O" & LR)
```

Comment: Thank you. As I mentioned in my comment I tried to put the brackets before the semicolon and that didn't work.

Comment: @D.Todor when you have too many `"` and `(` use `Debug.Print` of the `Formula` string you are trying (I Do)

Comment: @ShaiRado any reason for that extra brackets? I remember a wise person who said something like "an answer is perfect, if you cannot omit anything without changing the meaning". Therefore you can omit the extra brackets like sktneer did in his answer without changing the math!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this...

```
Range("P2:P" & LR) = Evaluate("(I2:I" & LR & "+J2:J" & LR & ")*O2:O" & LR)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LR = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("P2:P" & LR).formulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-7]+RC[-6])*RC[-1]"
```

This will do (I+J)*O